# Create two arrays for two fields, keeping sort order of arrays in sync (without subquery)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sorting, aggregate-functions

There is no rhyme or reason for this question other than I was curious about how one would go about doing this.

**Platform:** while I was hoping for a SQL-Standard solution, my main concentration is with *PostgreSQL 8.4+*. (I know 9.0+ has some array sorting functions.)

```
SELECT    id, group, dt
FROM      foo
ORDER BY  id;
```

> ```
>   id   | group |    dt
> -------+-------+-----------
>    1   |  foo  | 2012-01-01
>    1   |  bar  | 2012-01-03
>    1   |  baz  | 2012-01-02
>    2   |  foo  | 2012-01-01
>    3   |  bar  | 2012-01-01
>    4   |  bar  | 2012-01-01
>    4   |  baz  | 2012-01-01
> ```

I know the following query is wrong, but the result is similar to what I'm after; a way to tie the two fields (sorting of `group` should also sort `dt`):

```
SELECT    id, sort_array(array_agg(group)), array_agg(dt)
FROM      foo
GROUP BY  id;
```

> ```
>   id   |     group      |                dt
> -------+----------------+------------------------------------
>    1   |  {bar,baz,foo} | {2012-01-03,2012-01-02,2012-01-01}
>    2   |  {foo}         | {2012-01-01}
>    3   |  {bar}         | {2012-01-01}
>    4   |  {bar,baz}     | {2012-01-01,2012-01-01}
> ```

Is there an easy way to tie the fields for sorting, w/o using a subquery?  Perhaps build an array of arrays and then unnest?

Comment: I welcome downvotes, but wished I knew why to improve for next time.

Comment: +1 I upvoted, it is a decent question. The program version is missing, though (that's *always* a must.) And the rationale behind the request.

Comment: I don't mind being criticized.  All for self-improvement.  Updated the question, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your column name `group` to `grp` because `group` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in Postgres and every SQL standard and shouldn't be used as identifier.

I understand your question like this:

*Get the two arrays sorted in identical sort order so that the same element position corresponds to the same row in both arrays.*

**Use a subquery** or **CTE** and order the rows before you aggregate.

```
SELECT id, array_agg(grp) AS grp, array_agg(dt) AS dt
FROM  (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY id, grp, dt
    ) x
GROUP  BY id;
```

That's **faster** than to use individual [`ORDER BY` clauses in the aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) `array_agg()` like [@Mosty demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773171/939860) (and which has been there since PostgreSQL 9.0). Mosty also interprets your question differently and uses the proper tools for his interpretation.

#### Is `ORDER BY` in a subquery safe?

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

> The aggregate functions `array_agg`, `json_agg`, [...] as well as
>   similar user-defined aggregate functions, produce meaningfully
>   different result values depending on the order of the input values.
>   This ordering is unspecified by default, but can be controlled by
>   writing an `ORDER BY` clause within the aggregate call, as shown in
>   Section [4.2.7](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). Alternatively, supplying the input values from a
>   sorted subquery will usually work. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT xmlagg(x) FROM (SELECT x FROM test ORDER BY y DESC) AS tab;
> ```
>
> Beware that this approach can fail if the outer query level contains
>   additional processing, such as a join, because that might cause the
>   subquery's output to be reordered before the aggregate is computed.

So yes, it's safe in the example.

#### Without subquery

If you really *need* a solution *without subquery*, you can:

```
SELECT id
     , array_agg(grp ORDER BY grp)
     , array_agg(dt  ORDER BY grp, dt)
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id;
```

Note the `ORDER BY grp, dt`. I sort by `dt` in addition to break ties and make the sort order unambiguous. Not necessary for `grp`, though.

There is also a completely different way to do this, with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id
     , array_agg(grp) OVER w AS grp
     , array_agg(dt)  OVER w AS dt
FROM   tbl
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY grp, dt
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER  BY id;
```

Note the `DISTINCT ON (id)` instead of just `DISTINCT` which produces the same result but performs faster by an order of magnitude because we do not need an extra sort.

I ran some tests and this is almost as fast as the other two solutions. As expected, the subquery version was still fastest. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see for yourself.

Comment: I knew someone was going to comment on the group reserved word :) I thought foo would be enough to show it's only an example.  But I was more inquiring about a way to sort w/o the use of an explicit subquery.

Comment: @vol7ron: It was bound to happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know to flatten this out is to use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html). Here is what the query would look like:

```
--We first need to create the order hierarchy to recurse properly
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY group) AS rownum
INTO TEMP TableToRecurse
FROM foo

WITH RECURSIVE FinalOutput (id, group, dt, rownum) AS
(
--Anchor row of recursion
SELECT id, group, dt, rownum
FROM TableToRecurse 
WHERE rownum = 1
UNION ALL 
--Recursion piece
SELECT tr.id, FinalOutput.group || ', ' || tr.group, 
    FinalOutput.dt || ', ' || tr.dt, tr.rownum
FROM TableToRecurse AS tr
    JOIN FinalOutput
        ON  FinalOutput.id = tr.id AND FinalOutput.rownum = tr.rownum +1
)
--Final output only showing the last row (Max)
--Which should have everything concatenated together
SELECT FinalOutput.id, FinalOutput.group, FinalOutput.dt
FROM FinalOutput 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(rownum) AS MaxRowNum, id
        FROM FinalOutput
        GROUP BY id
    ) AS MaxForEach
        ON FinalOutput.id = MaxForEach.id 
            AND FinalOutput.rownum = MaxForEach.MaxRowNum
```

Comment: Pretty interesting - I'll have to look at this in more detail.

Comment: This is not valid PostgreSQL syntax. Looks like it is for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, my background is SQL Server, but I did double check that this could be done in PostGreSQL (see my link). I noticed that the temp table syntax is different, but I believe that should be fixed now. Otherwise, what is wrong with this?

Comment: Yeah, I saw when there were hash marks it wasn't Postgres, but I think the Recursive structure between the two databases are the same.

Comment: @JustinPihony: The string concatenation operator in Postgres is `||` - which is also the SQL standard. `+` is not defined for strings, that's a Microsoft thing. You also still have the `#` in front of the temp table name. You might be interested in the site `sqlfiddle.com` to test the your syntax. The basic structure of the recursive CTE works, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id,
  array_agg(agroup order by agroup) as AGroup,
  array_agg(dt order by dt desc) as dt
from t
group by id
```

This should work on PostgreSQL 9.1+

Comment: I think what I was after would be more `array_agg(dt order by agroup) as dt`, I don't have 9.1, but +1 anyways as I'm sure I'll have it in the future