# Distinct values from an array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, distinct

Following tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE guys ( guy_id integer primary key, guy text );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sales ( log_date date, sales_guys integer[], sales smallint );
INSERT INTO guys VALUES(1,'john'),(2,'joe');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('2016-01-01', '{1,2}', 2),('2016-01-02','{1,2}',4);
```

Following query works great to show names on a given date:

```
SELECT log_date, sales_guys, ARRAY_AGG(guy), sales 
FROM sales 
JOIN guys ON 
   guys.guy_id = ANY(sales.sales_guys) 
GROUP BY log_date, sales_guys, sales 
ORDER BY log_date ASC;

  log_date  | sales_guys | array_agg  | sales 
------------+------------+------------+-------
 2016-01-01 | {1,2}      | {john,joe} |     2
 2016-01-02 | {1,2}      | {john,joe} |     4
```

Following query problematically gives me a name per date per guy, so here each name twice, and so on):

```
SELECT sales_guys, ARRAY_AGG(guy), SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM sales
JOIN guys ON guys.guy_id = ANY(sales.sales_guys)
GROUP BY sales_guys;
```

Yields:

```
 sales_guys |      array_agg      | sales 
------------+---------------------+-------
 {1,2}      | {john,joe,john,joe} |    12
```

Is there a way to somehow reduce the `ARRAY_AGG` call to give only the unique names?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to aggregate *exactly*. Sales for the same team? Would you group `{1,2}` with `{2,1}`? And always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

There is no kind of order you can trust without `ORDER BY`. Except that elements of arrays, when unnested, come in array order. If your query does more with the result, it may be re-ordered, though.

You an simply add `ORDER BY` to any aggregate function in Postgres:

```
SELECT s.sales_guys, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT g.guy ORDER BY g.guy) AS names, SUM(s.sales) AS sum_sales
FROM   sales s
JOIN   guys  g ON g.guy_id = ANY(s.sales_guys)
GROUP  BY s.sales_guys;
```

But that's obviously *not* the original order of array elements. And the query has other issues ... Neither `IN` nor `= ANY()` care about order of elements in the set, list or array on the right side:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

#### Proper solution

For this task (attention to the details!):

*Get the total `sales` per array `sales_guys`, where the order of elements makes a difference (arrays `'{1,2}'` and `'{2,1}'` are not the same) and `sales_guys` has neither duplicate nor NULL elements. Add an array of resolved names in matching order.*

Use `unnest()` with `WITH ORDINALITY`. and aggregate arrays *before* you resolve names, that's cheaper and less error prone.

```
SELECT s.*, g.
FROM  (
   SELECT sales_guys, sum (sales) AS total_sales                -- aggregate first in subquery
   FROM   sales
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s
, LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(guy ORDER BY ord) AS names                  -- order by original order
   FROM   unnest(s.sales_guys) WITH ORDINALITY sg(guy_id, ord)  -- with order of elements
   LEFT   JOIN guys g USING (guy_id)                            -- LEFT JOIN to add NULL for missing guy_id
   ) g;
```

The `LATERAL` subquery can be joined with unconditional `CROSS JOIN` - comma (`,`) is shorthand notation - because the aggregate in the subquery *guarantees* a result for every row. Else you'd use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL .. ON true`.

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Create two arrays for two fields, keeping sort order of arrays in sync (without subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772837/sql-proper-way-to-sort-array-of-two-fields-without-subquery/9773201#9773201)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` inside of the aggregate:

```
SELECT sales_guys, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT guy), SUM(sales) AS sales FROM sales JOIN guys ON guys.guy_id = ANY(sales.sales_guys) GROUP BY sales_guys;
```

Comment: dang, that's obvious. Woof. Is there some kind of order you can trust in the DISTINCT call? Would they be ordered here by `guy_id` in `guys` or `guy` in `guys` or is it effectively random?

Comment: I think there is no defined order. You can fetch the _guys_ in the join by an ordered subquery or view first to get an ordered array.

Comment: hmm, I kind of hoped to get a guy_id array, and a guy array such that I could trust guy_id[1] == guy[1] but it doesn't seem possible w/o a subquery.