# UPDATE to remove duplicates from comma-separated list

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

In my Postgres db, I have a table with some columns where one column `B` has values as follows:

```
A      B
a1     b0, b1, b1
a2     b2, b3
a3     b4, b4, b5, b5
```

My expected output should be like this:

```
A      B
a1     b0, b1
a2     b2, b3
a3     b4, b5
```

Is there a simple `UPDATE` in Postgres to do this?

Comment: What is the type of column `B`. Is it a text field, json or array of something? The update function exists, but depends on the type of `B`

Comment: you shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place. That is a really bad design.

Comment: Any such question *needs* to provide actual table definition showing data types and constraints and the Postgres version in use. Also, why the redundant format of `b0,  b1,  b1` instead of just `0,  1,  1`? And why not an array or a normalized DB design? And: fold only consecutive duplicates or all? Preserve order of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific update statement depends on the type of column `b`, but there are really only 3 different ways this data could be stored, in a delimited string, an text array or a json

The update statement for the comma separated text field would be:

```
update mytable
set b = array_to_string(array(select distinct unnest(string_to_array(b, ', '))), ', ');
```

If `b` is an text array then:

```
update mytable
set b = array(select distinct unnest(b));
```

If `b` is a json array then:

```
update mytable
set b = array_to_json(array(select distinct value from json_array_elements_text(b)));
```

As you can see, the *cleanest* statement in is case results from the data being stored as a text array. If you must store an array of values in 1 column, do it using an array type.

However, I would also recommend normalizing your data.

These statements above will update all rows in the table, thus incurring a higher execution cost. I'll illustrate a way to reduce updates using the text array variant (as that requires the shortest sql query):

```
update mytable
set b = array(select distinct unnest(b))
where array_length(b_array, 1) != (select count(distinct c) from unnest(b) c);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could achieve this:

An UPDATE statement that unnests the elements and aggregates them back while removing duplicates:

```
update bad_design
  set b = t.b
from (
  select a, string_agg(distinct trim(t.w), ',') b
  from bad_design
    cross join unnest(string_to_array(b, ',')) as t(w)
  group by a
) t
where t.a = bad_design.a;
```

The other option if you need to do that very often, is to create a function that removes duplicates and use that in an UPDATE:

```
create or replace function cleanup(p_list text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(distinct trim(t.w), ',')
  from unnest(string_to_array(p_list, ',')) as t(w);
$$
language SQL;
```

Then you can use that like this:

```
update bad_design
  set b = cleanup(b);
```

---

The reason why this is so complicated is the fact that you did not properly normalize your data model. With a properly normalized model, you could simply create a UNIQUE index and prevent duplicates from being inserted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: current version of Postgres, data type of `B` is `text`, separator in your list is `', '`, remove *all* duplicates, preserve original order of elements, most or all rows have duplicates:

Then this should be simplest and fastest:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    B = array_to_string( ARRAY(
         SELECT elem
         FROM   unnest(string_to_array(B, ', ')) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, ord)
         GROUP  BY 1
         ORDER  BY min(ord)
         ), ', ');
```

The drawback: *all* rows are updated, even if nothing changes. If that affects more than a few rows, it can be avoided ...

If any assumptions do not hold, there may be a different / better / faster solution.

Related:

- [Distinct values from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810362/distinct-values-from-an-array/40813201#40813201)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)